# Keep only first 20 entries in string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string that contains calculations.  Each entry has a space in between the next.  How do I keep only the most recent 20 entries?

```
Label2.text += TextBox1.Text + "+" + TextBox2.Text + "=" + Label1.Text + " ";
```

Output is:

20+20=40 40+20=60 60+20=80

Comment: What is considered the "most recent"?

Comment: newest entries are tacked on the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string.Split(' ').Reverse().Take(20)`

or, as David & Groo have pointed out in other comments

`string.Split(' ').Reverse().Take(20).Reverse()`

Comment: Label2.Text = string.Split(' ').Reverse().Take(20); results in CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'string.Split(params char[])'

Comment: yes, in the example, replace `string` with the string you want to process

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to maintain a queue of items (a First-In-First-Out structure):

```
// have a field which will contain calculations
Queue<string> calculations = new Queue<string>();

void OnNewEntryAdded(string entry)
{
    // add the entry to the end of the queue...
    calculations.Enqueue(entry);

    // ... then trim the beginning of the queue ...
    while (calculations.Count > 20)
        calculations.Dequeue();

    // ... and then build the final string
    Label2.text = string.Join(" ", calculations);
}
```

Note that the `while` loop will probably only run once, and can be easily replaced with an `if` (but this is just a failsafe in case the queue is being updated from multiple places).

Also, I wonder if a `Label` is really the right control for keeping a list of items?

Answer (score 1):

Use a string split

```
string.Split(' ').Take(20)
```

if most recent is at the end then you can use `OrderByDescending` then `Take20`

```
string.Split(' ').Select((n, i) => new { Value = n, Index = i }).OrderByDescending(i => i.Index).Take(20);
```

Comment: ..gives an array and takes the first 20, not most recently-entered 20

Comment: can you define what the 'most recent' means then. is this the end of the string?

Comment: `string.Split(' ').Reverse().Take(20)`?

Comment: @paul: that would return them in reverse, which is possibly not what OP wanted.

Comment: @Groo then maybe string.Split(' ').Reverse().Take(20).Reverse()?

Comment: @Paul your answer is better, you should post it.

Comment: it's still an array.. I would think it should be joined back into a string?

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] calculations = yourString.Split(' ');
string[] last20 = calculations.Skip(Math.Max(0, calculations.Count() - 20).Take(20);
```